# which one is correct between how long haven’t we met or how long we haven’t met

Tags: present-perfect

1.How long haven’t we met each other ? 
2.How long we haven’t met each other ?

Which one is correct form of negative structure, please help me , thank you

Comment: Neither. What exactly are you trying to say (or write)? I can think of more than one possible interpretation of the two phrases.

Comment: Presumably "How long is it since we met?" (or "How long has it been...")

Comment: Actually I want to know how to say/ask my friend ,,,, we didn’t meet long time “ how long we .........? ( for correct grammar)